# Grab an item from a table and edit it in modal in SpringBoot/Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table that runs through all of the logs and puts each log and its' pertaining details in a row. I want to click on a row that pops up a modal with that line's log's information so I can edit it. I am not sure how to grab that specific log in SpringBoot to insert into the th:object="${}" in the form, as I can't put the object of one log in the controller function because I don't know which one people will click on. How would I go about grabbing the id/log info based on which table row they clicked on, to populate the modal?

Would the best way be to use javascript? Or do I need to add some sort of logic in the controller?

Here is the table:

```html
                        <table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-show-toggle="true" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-search="true"  data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>When</th>
                                <th>Subject</th>
                                <th>Notes</th>
                                <th class="text-right"><a class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a></th>
                                <th class="text-right"><a class="trigger btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="log : ${logs}">
                                <td th:if="${log.time!=null}" th:text="${{#temporals.format(log.time,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a')}}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${log.subject}"></td>
                                <td style="white-space: pre-wrap;" th:text="${log.notes}"></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><a th:value="${log}" class="trigger-edit-log"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><a th:href="@{|/delete/callLog/${log.id}|}"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Here is the javascript to open the modal..I tried to set the clicked line to a variable callLog and inserted that into the th:object of the modal, but that didn't work:

```html
            $(document).on('click', '.trigger-edit-log', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var callLog = $(this);
                $('#modal-edit-log').iziModal('open');
            });
```

Here is the modal

```html
                <div id="modal-edit-log" data-izimodal-title="Edit Log" class="modal">
                    <form th:action="@{/save/log}" th:object=??? method="post" style="padding:0 10px;">
                        <br/>
                        <!--<input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>-->
                        <!--<input type="hidden" th:value="*{client.id}" th:name="client" th:id="client"/>-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right"><label>Subject:</label></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7"><input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{subject}"/> </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right"><label>Notes:</label></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7"><input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{notes}"/> </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

My controller, if you need to see it:

```html
    @RequestMapping(value="/callLogs/client/{id}")
    public String getCallLogs(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id){
        Client client=clientRepository.findById(id);
        CallLog newCallLog=new CallLog();
        List<CallLog> logs=callLogRepository.findByClientOrderByTimeDesc(client);
        List<Role> assignees= roleRepository.findByIsTaskAssignee(true);
        List<Task> tasks=taskRepository.findByClient(client);

        model.addAttribute("assignees",assignees);
        model.addAttribute("newTask",new Task());
        model.addAttribute("tasks",tasks);
        model.addAttribute("client",client);
        model.addAttribute("logs",logs);
        model.addAttribute("newCallLog",newCallLog);
        return ("callLogs");
    }
```

Comment: You just need to somehow parameterize each log line in the list you display so that clicking on a particular line passes enough unique information to the modal that it can display the right information. - you seem to already be doing this with `th:value="${log}"`. - I'm a back-end guy, so I'm not great with the particulars of HTML and JavaScript.  But I've done a lot of this, where our HTML guy will give me a template, and I'll just parameterize it to drop the right information into place.  So the mechanism is clear to me.

Comment: @Steve, right, but if I try to just pass log into the thymeleaf object in the modal, it hasn't been bound (usually do that through the controller fn) so I get this error: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'log' available as request attribute

Comment: By the time the HTML is returned to the client, there is no `${log}`.  That variable is interpreted on the server at the time that the template is turned into the actual page you're going to return. - so you're not passing that into the modal.  Instead, you're extracting something from `log` and putting that in the call to your modal. - maybe I need to look closer at your code.

Comment: I do understand the problem you have, I think.  You have a bunch of information about each log entry.  You don't want to display it all, but you want to display details about each line once it's clicked, right?

Comment: You have two options: 1) get all of the information into the initial HTML page you send back, even though it might not be displayed right away, or 2) make a second call back to the server to get the details once a user clicks on a particular line.  If youo want to go with #1, you have to figure out some way to expand the information you have into the page you send back.  The fundamental problem has nothing to do with Thymeleaf.  You should ask yourself what you'd want your HTML to look like if you hard coded it.  Then you can figure out how to have Thymeleaf produce the same thing.

Comment: @Steve, correct, my modal is coming up empty thinking it's trying to create a new log. What I need is when I click on the line, with the value of log or log's id, to grab the object that is tied to that id and populate the modal fields with that information. Not sure how to go about grabbing the object not just the object id. Sound's like from your two options, I could use Javascript to make an ajax call when the modal button is clicked?

Comment: Right.  If you don't want to go back to the server, then think about how you'd do this statically for say 5 items.  That's the first problem to solve.  Then, since you don't want the page to be hard-coded, you bring in Thymeleaf to have the page be generated dynamically.  But do you understand the division here?  Thymeleaf is just writing a page of HTML for you.  It has nothing to do with the logic when the page is interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Can you call back to the server for the details of a single log entry?  I think that is how this would normally be done.  Then you really would just encode the ID into the HTML for each line in the list of log entries. - If you can't, then all the data has to be in that initial HTML page.  I'm not a HTML guy, so I can't think off hand how to do that.  I suppose you could have Thymeleaf generate a Javascript data structure for you.  Or, you could somehow embed all the information into each row of your table.

Comment: I understand I have to grab the object or do a server call for the information, but if if I do that, I am still unsure what to put in the th:object="${ }" because that needs to come through the spring-boot controller function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191694/discussion-between-steve-and-stacie).